# Do not concatenate text displayed with setText issue + App crashing when other language than default lang is used

Tags: java, android, xml, string, concatenation

I have defined strings in strings.xml (and the corresponding files for other languages).

When the app executes this line (and not just the one, others like this one) :
    timeTextView.setText(substr2 + " " + getString(R.string.shours) + " " + minutereal + " " + getString(R.string.sminutes));

in the default (english) language, the result on the screen is ok ! But if I change language on the phone and try to use the app, everything works ok until I click the button (when the result should be displayed), then app crashes.

I searched on stackoverflow (and not only), but I don't know how to solve the problem.

Strings defined in values\strings.xml :

```
<string name="shours">hour(s),</string>
<string name="sminutes">minute(s)</string>
```

I have tried :

```
timeTextView.setText(getString(substr2, R.string.shours, minutereal, R.string.sminutes));
```

but this one doesn't work at all.

This one :

```
timeTextView.setText(substr2 + " stunde(n), " + minutereal + "  minute(n)");
```

works as well as the first option, but same result, works on default language, and as the first option, I get the same warning : Do not concatenate text displayed with setText issue .

logcat from crash :

```
08-21 16:21:02.834 23866-23866/com.example.android.test_app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.test_app, PID: 23866
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1
at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:504)
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1333)
at com.example.android.test_app.MainActivity.displayTimeReal(MainActivity.java:91)
at com.example.android.test_app.MainActivity.access$200(MainActivity.java:12)
at com.example.android.test_app.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:31)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
```

So, as I said earlier, I have allready searched for an answer, it's not that I'm lazy or anything, but I just don't get it ... (dumb maybe :P ).

This is the entire script for one of the values that supposed to be shown on the screen after the data is inserted and button pushed :

```
private void displayTimeReal(double timpreal) {
    DecimalFormat formattr = new DecimalFormat();
    formattr.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    String formattedTimpR = formattr.format(timpreal);
    String substr1 = formattedTimpR.substring(formattedTimpR.indexOf(".") + 1); //decimals
    String substr2 = formattedTimpR.substring(0, formattedTimpR.indexOf(".")); //unit
    double minutereal = Double.parseDouble(substr1);
    minutereal = minutereal * 0.6;
    TextView timeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rezultat_ore_real);
    timeTextView.setText(substr2 + " " + getString(R.string.shours) + " " + minutereal + " " + getString(R.string.sminutes));
    //timeTextView.setText(getString(substr2, R.string.shours, minutereal, R.string.sminutes));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !!!

Thank you for your time and you never-ending (hopefully :P ) patience and support !

P.S. The button that does the magic :

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/butto"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/sbutton"
        android:textColor="#0277BD"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

and the entire thing to display :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.butto)
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    displayTarget((procente / Double.parseDouble(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.vZeit))
                            .getText().toString())) * mitarbeiter);
                    displayTime((Double.parseDouble(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.aufGesSt))
                            .getText().toString())) / (procente / Double.parseDouble(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.vZeit))
                            .getText().toString()) * mitarbeiter));
                    displayTimeReal((Double.parseDouble(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.aufGesSt))
                            .getText().toString())) / (procente / Double.parseDouble(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.vZeit))
                            .getText().toString()) * mitarbeiter));

                }
            });
}
```

Comment: What is at line number 91?

Comment: line 91 :         String substr2 = formattedTimpR.substring(0, formattedTimpR.indexOf(".")); //unit

Comment: line 12 : public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Comment: line 31 :                         displayTimeReal((Double.parseDouble(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.aufGesSt))

Comment: There is no `.` in the string. That's why its throwing `IndexOutOfBound` exception.

Comment: how come on default language doesn't crash ?! only on translated languages ?! same data input, on default lang does what it suppoes, on translated languages crashes ...

Comment: What's the value? Try printing it in logs before extracting the substring.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I forgot to mention this is my second week in xml and java :)

Comment: Which is the language you are trying to convert to? What is the value of `timpreal`?

Comment: defauld language is english (though it should be german). translated languages romanian and german (for now, thinking of adding others). timp

Comment: displayTimeReal((Double.parseDouble(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.aufGesSt))
                                .getText().toString())) / (procente / Double.parseDouble(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.vZeit))
                                .getText().toString()) * mitarbeiter));

Comment: private void displayTimeReal(double timpreal) {
        DecimalFormat formattr = new DecimalFormat();
        formattr.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        String formattedTimpR = formattr.format(timpreal);
        String substr1 = formattedTimpR.substring(formattedTimpR.indexOf(".") + 1); //decimals
        String substr2 = formattedTimpR.substring(0, formattedTimpR.indexOf(".")); //unit
double minutereal = Double.parseDouble(substr1);
        minutereal = minutereal * 0.6;
        TextView timeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rezultat_ore_real);

Comment: last line from displayTimeReal(double timpreal) { is :        timeTextView.setText(substr2 + " " + getString(R.string.shours) + " " + minutereal + " " + getString(R.string.sminutes));

Comment: Stop adding the same code in comments.

Comment: What is the value of `timpreal` ?

Comment: with the code I have tried to explain to you the value of timpreal . timpreal is returned after the user imputs some data and the app does the math ...

Comment: it does not have a fixed value .... because of that I pasted the code ...

Comment: @Robert What are you trying to print in the TextView?

Comment: what is the value that you are testing with and it's failing?

Comment: any value that I input in the translated language app ... crashes. Just as vell as any value given in default language, does the job without crash. Value(s) has nothing to do with it ... :( . In TextView .... well I have to print the time I calculated (from industrial time to normal 60 minutes time). That is why I need so separate the units from the decimals and the decimals I have to multiply with 0,6 ... and some text, of course (ex : 3 hour(s), 42 minute(s) )

Comment: @Robert Which language are you trying to convert to?

Comment: as I have said before : default language is english. translated languages are romanian and german (for now, thinking of adding others)

Answer (score 0):

The answer for the second part of the problem (App crashing when other language than default lang is used) was solved here :

[Android app crashes if installed as apk, works if runned trough Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39316379/android-app-crashes-if-installed-as-apk-works-if-runned-trough-android-studio/39333022#39333022)

The answer, provided by user samgak :

The problem seems to be caused by the numbers being formatted differently based on the devices's Locale.

When you use a DecimalFormat object, the decimal separator is different depending on the device's language settings. For example in English it's a dot e.g. 3.14159 but in German it's a comma e.g. 3,14159.

This causes a problem because your code is always looking for a dot when you call indexOf().

You can fix this several ways. One way is to specify a locale when creating the DecimalFormat object, e.g:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
DecimalFormat formattr = (DecimalFormat)nf;
```

Or else you can just set the decimal separator:

DecimalFormat formattr = new DecimalFormat();
formattr.setDecimalSeparator('.');
However perhaps you want it to display differently for German users. In that case you can change your code that checks for the dot to check for whatever the correct character is:

```
String zecimaleTimpReal = formattedTimpR.substring(formattedTimpR.indexOf("" + formattr.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator()) + 1);
```

Adding to the empty string is just a trick to convert from a char to a String.

Be aware that there is also a "grouping symbol" which can be a comma or dot as well e.g. 123,456.78. You might want to disable grouping, like this:

```
formattr.setGroupingUsed(false);
```

@samgak - Thank you again !